# In a MAUI application, where is the best way to initialize some data when the application starts?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a MAUI application and I would like to initialize some data of the application when the application starts.

In my case, I have a default settings applications that is added as resource when I compile. In the startup, I check if I have any of this settings in Prefereces.Default, that is the storage of the application. If not, I copy the settings from the embedded resource to References.Default.

By the moment I am doing this in the MauiProgram.cs file, but I am not sure if this is the best place to do it.

Perhaps AppShell.xaml.cs is another possible place or perhaps app.xaml.cs.

Where should do this initialization?

where is the use of AppShell, App and MauiProgram?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a page for initialization and use that as the `App.MainPage`. When the initialization is done change the `App.MainPage` to an `AppShell` instance.

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App( InitPage init, AppShell shell )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // InitPage notifies on completion, so we change the MainPage to shell
        init.InitCompleted += ( s, e ) => MainPage = shell;
        MainPage = init;
    }
}
```

InitPage starts the initialization on appearing. The initialization itself is done inside the ViewModel

```
public partial class InitPage : ContentPage
{
    public InitPage( InitPageViewModel viewModel )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        Appearing += async ( s, e ) =>
        {
            await viewModel.InitializeAsync();
            InitCompleted?.Invoke( this, EventArgs.Empty );
        };
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> InitCompleted;
}
```

The ViewModel now can initialize any needed services

```
public class InitPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [Reactive] public string InitSection { get; private set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializeAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        await base.OnInitializeAsync( cancellationToken );
        InitSection = "Warm up DataServices";
        await Task.Delay( 2000 );
        InitSection = "Expand Images";
        await Task.Delay( 4000 );
        InitSection = "Feed the pets";
        await Task.Delay( 3000 );
    }
}
```

A full sample app [is on github](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-MauiInit)

Comment: An advantage of this approach, is that the initialization code runs AFTER InitPage is displayed. This has two benefits if initialization might take awhile: 1. Can show something to user, to let them know the app is loading. 2. Because something is displayed, the OS won't kill the app if it takes too many seconds (e.g. timeout waiting for a response from a server). No worry about "app startup time too long" on a slow device or a bad internet connection. Its also a good place to have user `Login` if needed.