Is it possible to initiate a method in the App.xml.cs file instead of a content page?
I'm building a .NET Maui app where the user has to initially select a database. So instead of a content page appearing with no data because a database has not been selected, I'm looking to initially run a method that would look for a a database on the computer.
If no database was found, a popup screen would appear to create a new database. If databases were found then a different popup screen would be displayed listing all the available databases for the user to select.
So my question would be can I somehow place a method in the App.xaml.cs file that would do all of wha I just explained? Or would I have to do it a different way?

yes, there are multiple lifecycle events you can hook into to do this initailiazation.  However, you need a page displayed in order to do any UI, and the OS itself expect the user to be presented with UI as soon as possible.  You should at least display a placeholder page while you're initializing so your user knows the app is working

Jason - So you're saying get maybe a popup screen to initially run and place the method in its OnAppering event. something like that?

you can run the method from App.xaml.cs, but you need to display something to the user while it runs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247216/in-a-maui-application-where-is-the-best-way-to-initialize-some-data-when-the-ap
